# datetime2: scientific english format

Tags: datetime2

I'd like to typeset dates with the `datetime2` package in English in the format commonly used in scientific or technical writing, that is:

- time in 24-hour format;
- dates in the format: "29 October 2018" (no commas, no ordinals).

How can this be done? None of the English language packages seem to support this format. I'm using LuaLaTeX and polyglossia, just in case it matters. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `\DTMsettimestyle` to set a time style that overrides the current date-time style. The English `datetime2` styles that use day month year ordering all have options `ord`, `daymonthsep` and `monthyearsep` that allow you to make minor adjustments to the way the ordinal is display and the separators between the day and month and between the month and year.

For example, with `en-GB` the default options are `ord=level`, `daymonthsep={\space}` and `monthyearsep={\space}`, so the only option that needs changing for your required date style is `ord`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[en-GB]{datetime2}

\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=omit}

\DTMsettimestyle{iso}

\begin{document}
Today: \today. Current time: \DTMcurrenttime.

\end{document}
```

(Other locales may have different default options. Check the [`datetime2-english` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datetime2-contrib/datetime2-english/datetime2-english.pdf) for available locales and their settings.)

The date style uses the `en-GB` regional style, because `en-GB` is used as a package option, but the time style uses `iso` because `\DTMsettimestyle` overrides the date-time style (set implicitly with `\DTMsetstyle{en-GB}` when the package was loaded). This produces:

[image: Today: 29 October 2018. Current time: 17:53:53.]

If you don't want the seconds with the `iso` style you can use the `showseconds=false` package option:

```
\usepackage[en-GB,showseconds=false]{datetime2}
```

With `polyglossia`, you need to move `\DTMsettimestyle` after the language change otherwise it will be reset:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=uk]{english}
\usepackage[en-GB,showseconds=false]{datetime2}

\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=omit,daymonthsep={\space}}

\begin{document}
\DTMsettimestyle{iso}

Today: \today. Current time: \DTMcurrenttime.

\end{document}
```

Other options include modifying the appropriate language date hook. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=uk]{english}
\usepackage[en-GB,showseconds=false]{datetime2}

\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=omit}

\renewcommand{\dateenglish}{%
  \DTMsetdatestyle{en-GB}%
  \DTMsettimestyle{iso}%
}

\begin{document}

Today: \today. Current time: \DTMcurrenttime.

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, if the document only has a single language, use `useregional=false` and set both the date and time style as appropriate in the preamble. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=uk]{english}
\usepackage[en-GB,useregional=false,showseconds=false]{datetime2}

\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=omit,daymonthsep={\space}}
\DTMsetdatestyle{en-GB}
\DTMsettimestyle{iso}

\begin{document}

Today: \today. Current time: \DTMcurrenttime.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to put the example of a non-ordinal date somewhere prominent in the datetime2 and datetime2-english documentation?